# Measuring Download speed when using Python's FTPLib

Tags: python, ftplib

I am downloading files using the Python FTP lib , is there a way to get the current download speed.

If not is there another lib that I can use that will provide me with speed info ?

Answer (score 1):

What's to stop you from providing your own callback to [`retrbinary`](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrbinary)/[`retrlines`](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrlines) that would calculate the current download speed? You'll know how much data has been downloaded and can trivially take time measurements.